# Why divide diameter by square root of 2 to get a diameter of a circle of half the area?

Tags: geometry

I would be very grateful if you can help me with this problem.

I am trying to explain in the simplest terms possible the sequence of f-stops in photography.

The common f-stop rounded sequence is:

f/1  f/1.4  f/2  f/2.8  f/4  f/5.6  f/8  f/11  f/16  f/22  f/32  f/45  f/64 etc.

What this implies is that if you take the focal length of a lens (f) and divide it by the first number in the sequence, 1, you get the diameter of the aperture. So if we have a 50mm lens, you would divide 50mm/1 which gives you 1.

The f-stop sequence is organised in such a way that each subsequent stop gives you a diameter for a circle whose area is exactly half of the one preceding it.

I know that if you want to get an area of a circle with half the area of an existing circle you would take the diameter and divide it by the √2.

So if we calculate the area of a circle by using this formula:

$$A = \pi \times  r^2$$

or if we want to work with a diameter we would use

$$A = \pi \times \left ( \dfrac d2 \right)^2$$

So I think (I am not sure), if we wanted to calculate half the area we would then use:

$$\dfrac A2  =  \dfrac {\pi}2 \times \dfrac {\left ( \dfrac d 2 \right)^2}2 $$

So my question is, how do we get that

$$ \dfrac A2 = \dfrac  d {\sqrt 2}$$ ?

And another related questions- photography also uses shutter speeds. Again, each subsequent number is half the time of the previous. They are an approximation of the following geometric progression:

1/1  1/2  1/4  1/8  1/16  1/32  1/64  1/128  1/256  1/512  1/1024 (where these are also rounded off).

I noticed that if you calculate the square root of each one of denominators you get the same sequence (again rounded off):

1  1.4  2  2.8  4  5.6  8  11  16  22  32  45 etc.

So again, how can I explain and relate the sequence of the shutter speeds to the sequence of apertures, and why do I halve the number when working with shutter speeds, and divide the number by a square root in the case of apertures?

This is probably very simple but I am not very good at maths so I would be very grateful if you could explain this to me.

Comment: Please use Mathjax for the math Thank you.

Comment: Sorry! I was not aware of Mathjax but I hope my question still makes sense.

Comment: Yes no problem.

Comment: Um... you explained it all in your question.  What's left to explain?  If $d_1$ and $d_2$ are two diameters.  And if $d_2 = \frac {d_1}{\sqrt 2}$.  ANd then the area of the first circle $A_1 = \pi (\frac {d_1}2)^2 = \frac {\pi d_1^2}4$.  And the area of the second is $A_2= \pi (\frac {d_1}2)^2 = $$\pi (\frac {\frac {d_1}{\sqrt 2}}2)^2 = $$\pi (\frac{\frac {d_1^2}2}4)=$$ \frac {\pi d_1^2}8= \frac {\frac {\pi d_1^2}4}2 = \frac {A_1}2$.

Comment: I find it difficult to follow but how come (12)2=
A
2
=
π
(
d
1
2
)
2
=
 (12√2)2

Comment: I find it difficult to follow but how come (1/2)^2 = π{ [ (d1)/√2 ] / 2 }^2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the area is proportional
to the square of the radius:
$A = \pi r^2$
or
$r = \sqrt{A/\pi}$,
which means that
$r$ is proportional
to the square root of the area.

Therefore,
if $A$ is replaced by
$A/2$,
$r$ becomes
$\sqrt{(A/2)/\pi}
=\dfrac{\sqrt{A/\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}
$.

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to express this formula using the diameter (d). Sorry, I am really bad!

Comment: Just  put d = 2r or r = d/2.

Answer (score 1):

The area $A$ of a circle of diameter $d$ is
$$A = \pi \left( \frac{d}{2} \right)^2 = \frac{\pi d^2}{4}$$

Let's say we have two diameters $d_1$ and $d_2$, and their corresponding areas $A_1$ and $A_2$:
$$A_1 = \frac{\pi d_1^2}{4}, \quad A_2 = \frac{\pi d_2^2}{4}$$
Let's see what the diameters are if $A_2 = 2 A_1 \gt 0$ (so $d_1 \gt 0$ and $d_2 \gt 0$ too):
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\pi d_2^2}{4} &= 2 \frac{\pi d_1^2}{4} \\
d_2^2 &= 2 d_1^2 \\
\sqrt{d_2^2} &= \sqrt{2 d_1^2} \\
d_2 &= \sqrt{2} d_1 \\
\end{aligned}$$
Above, we are allowed to take the square root because both sides are nonnegative, since $d_1 \gt 0$ and $d_2 \gt 0$.

In other words, the square root comes from the fact that the area is proportional to the square of the diameter; and the square root of 2 comes from the fact that we are comparing areas whose ratio is 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can just consider the formula for area of a circle,
which is
$ \pi\times  r^2.$

That's the area of some circle of some radius $r$.
What radius do we have to use in order to get double the area?

Let's make an inspired guess that we want the radius to be $\sqrt2\times r.$
So now we have a new, obviously larger (larger radius) circle with area
$\pi\times \left(\sqrt2\times r \right)^2$.

But let's see what that's equal to:

\begin{align}
 \pi\times \left(\sqrt2\times r \right)^2
&= \pi \times \left(\sqrt2\right)^2 \times r^2 && \text{because $(ab)^2 = a^2b^2$}\\
&= \pi \times 2 \times r^2 \\
&= 2\times\left(\pi \times r^2\right) && \text{associativity and commutativity of multiplication}\\
\end{align}

So before we had $\pi\times r^2,$ and now we have
$2\times\left(\pi \times r^2\right)$,
that is, exactly twice as much area, where $r$ is still the same number.

So to double the area, we just have to multiply the radius by $\sqrt2.$

The diameter is just exactly twice the radius, so when you multiply the radius by $\sqrt2$ you also multiply the diameter by $\sqrt2.$

So to double the area, multiply the diameter by $\sqrt2.$

If you want to get half the area, just suppose you started with the larger circle; now you have to divide its diameter by $\sqrt2$ to get the diameter of the smaller circle, which has half the area.

Comment: Thanks. What I still don't understand is why did we use the square root of 2 and not just multiply and divide by 2.

Comment: If you multiply the diameter by $2$ you get a circle with $4$ times as much area.